# javascript in jsf/icefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, icefaces

I have file with jspx extension i write javascript like

```
function isNumber(inputId){

            var value = document.getElementById('mainForm:'+ inputId).value;
            var  s = value.length;

            while(s >= 0){
                var c = value.charAt(s);
                if(c > "9"){
                    alert("Value must be digit");
                    document.getElementById('mainForm:'+ inputId).value = "";
                    document.getElementById('mainForm:'+ inputId).focus();
                    return false;
                }
                s --;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

that work perfect but when i check if condition like  if(c > "9" || c < "0") it will gives error like

```
com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /WEB-INF/includes/templates/cc-classic-template.jspx: Error Traced[line: 386] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

After long observation i found that <(less than) sign will create problem.
Is JSF not support < sign ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the escaping and CDATA answers:

If you want to check if a value is a number, there is a javascript built-in function for that: `isNaN`

Here is an example:

```
if (isNaN(document.getElementById('mainForm:'+ inputId).value))
  {
    alert("Please enter digits");
    document.getElementById(obj).focus();
    document.getElementById(obj).select();
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

Enclose your Javascript in CDATA Sections:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

    function isNumber(inputId){

            var value = document.getElementById('mainForm:'+ inputId).value;
            var  s = value.length;

            while(s >= 0){
                var c = value.charAt(s);
                if(c > "9"){
                    alert("Value must be digit");
                    document.getElementById('mainForm:'+ inputId).value = "";
                    document.getElementById('mainForm:'+ inputId).focus();
                    return false;
                }
                s --;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //Code containing "<" also comes in this section

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As explained by Matt Handy, you could not use the `<` or `>` sign in your JSPX, as this is a XML format. You have three solutions regarding your problem:

- Escape by using `&lt;` or `&gt;`.
- Use `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` to hold your JavaScript code in your page.
- Set your JavaScript code in a separate `.js` file, and load it in your JSPX page.