# javascript in jsf xhtml template

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml

Trying to put the following in my JSF xhtml template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

</script>
```

I substituted the && with &amp&amp and &ux0026&ux0026 but they don't seem to work

The error I get is: Error Parsing /templates/template.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 8] Element type "a.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Does anyone if any suggestions/ideas how to get around this?

Comment: For some reason it took out the code: trying again  <script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
} </script>

Comment: Researched this some more and found that CDATA fixes the problem e.g.

Comment: Solved it this way e.g. //<![CDATA[ 
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
} //]]>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `<` in `i<a.length`, you should escape it too (`&lt;`), or use CDATA as you said.

Also see this related question: [javascript in jsf/icefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429420/javascript-in-jsf-icefaces)