# JSF2.0 using '<' and '>' in embedded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I develop a JSF-Page like this in Netbeans

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        ...

        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

        function drawShape()
        {
            ...

            var length = shapeCollection.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
               ...
            }
        }   
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body onload="drawShape();">
        <canvas id="myDrawing" width="500" height="500">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Now I get an error in this part `for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)`

if I replace `<` with `!=` it works

How can I aviod this problem?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429420/javascript-in-jsf-icefaces : use /* <![CDATA[ */ block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the XHTML specification for [Script and Style blocks](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8).

You need to wrap your inline JS with CDATA markers.